# How to normalize all vectors of vertices

Tags: vertices

I am searching for a tool that allows me to normalize all vertices, so for example, if I have a subdivided cube and then normalize all vertices I should get something like a sphere.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: To sphere: SHIFT-ALT-S + 1